# xor eax, eax in x64

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x86-64, patch-reversing

I have following code:

```
sub rsp, 40                 ; 00000028H
lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:$SG4237
call    printf
xor eax, eax
add rsp, 40                 ; 00000028H
ret 0
```

Why there is `xor eax, eax` , instead of `xor rax, rax`?

Comment: Because the return value is likely "int", which is 32-bit in most compiler models (LP64/LLP64).

Comment: [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137/995714)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In x64, any operation on a 32-bit register clears the top 32 bits of the corresponding 64-bit register too, so there's no need to use `xor rax, rax` which would necessitate an extra REX byte for encoding.